# Is there any option to add a prefix for /swagger-ui path? OpenApi

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger, openapi, springdoc

Do you have any idea how to add as a prefix for /swagger-ui, my application name?
smth like

```
springdoc:
  swagger-ui:
    path: classpath:/META-INF/swagger-ui
```

but the code above doesnt work at all. i'd like to access localhost:8080/application-service/swagger-ui instead of localhost:8080/swagger-ui (which this is resolved with springdoc.swagger-ui.path=/swagger-ui

I dont want to use:

```
server:
  servlet:
    context-path: /application-service
```

because all the endpoints will have a different route.
thankssss

Answer (score 1):

```yaml
springdoc:
  swagger-ui:
    path: "application-service"
```

When using the above method, you'll be able to access Swagger-UI at `http://localhost:8080/application-service`

Note that even using the above property will redirect you to `localhost:8080/swagger-ui`, but with the added advantage that you'll have a different URL to access the Swagger-UI. Also, as of yet the path can not have a `/` in it, meaning you can't have an n-level path to expose Swagger-UI (which in a way makes sense cause Swagger is reference documentation and should be easily accessibly).